# outside border for UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, border

I know I can create border using below code.

```
[[myImageView layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[myImageView layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
```

However this draw border inside image.

What I was looking is draw border outside ImageView.

***Note:***

**I search online for this and found below.**

1. *Can be done by using another image which will have border.*
2. *Can be done by drawing another view which is little bigger then current image.*

***Is there quick way (especially in-built in iOS), where I can draw border outside UIImageView? Any views?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no quickway in-built in iOS, there is no margin that you could set on the image layer.

If I were you, I'd develop a new class that inherit from UIView (ex UIImageWithBorderView) and which include a UIImageView and making the "UIImageWithBorderView" bigger than the UIImageView (and think about NOT to autoresize the UIImageView with the UIView parent, otherwise your UIImageView will be stretched, and prevent the UIImageWithBorderView from being smaller than the UIImageView frame), and then add borders to the "UIImageWithBorderView".
This way, your UIImageView will be intact and you'll have a specific, reusable composant for your needs.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try border with using imageview's frame ?

```
  CGFloat borderWidth = 5.0f;    
    self.imgview.frame = CGRectInset(self.imgview. frame, -borderWidth, -borderWidth);
    self.imgview. layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.imgview. layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
```